# Jquery not run at Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I use a template HTML file from output a web page from Google AppsScript.
I use  `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('listview');` 
At the  space at listview.html file i have a linked to jquery library :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

If i run the html template independent at browser the web is correctly and the jquery is connect but wehn i use google appscript the web run but not connect at jquery library

Why i can't connect the jquery library ?

Can help me 
Thank's

Comment: External links must be loaded over http`s` only.

Comment: Ok !!! It's right need a htpss url no run with http url .

Comment: But when i use HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('listview'); or  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(code); google not display directly the web , it show a message at beginning of page. How i can show only my code html ?  Thank's

Comment: Not possible. Users of your webapp need to know that google didn't create your app, since the  domain url is ``google.com``

Comment: But if i use the command  `return ContentService.createTextOutput(code); `  at this app return text write for me, and nothing about google message at web .

Comment: Because Text is just output. You can't lure your users to give out their passwords or any input for that matter. So, Google thinks it's safe

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS

> ["Active" content like scripts, external stylesheets, and XmlHttpRequests must be loaded over HTTPS, not HTTP.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#https_required_for_active_content)